# String comparison and replacing with bold text if it is a match

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

Had this morning a brain teaser took me over an hour coming up with something that works.

Task is:
Compare 2 strings, the text from the field and data-row-internalnumber, see if they match and bold, only the last letters in the field, take away spaces and + sign, don't change the spaces in the field when writing it out again in bold.
The spaces from the field and data-row-internalnumber do not always match, that is what consumed my time.
My strong side is not regex, but I know we can do amazing things with it.  Isn't there a better way to write this code with regex?

http://jsfiddle.net/kjarisk/7y9mX/

Expected output should be the field but with bold endings if they match the data-row-internalnumber.

Here is the code I came up with(mockup of real code, used jquery):

```
<ul>
        <li data-row-internalnumber="+123">+345 555 123</li>
        <li data-row-internalnumber="+2 002">+345 552 002</li>
        <li data-row-internalnumber="+135">+345 555 1135</li>
        <li data-row-internalnumber="123">+345 555 5123</li>
        <li data-row-internalnumber="21 3">+345 555 213</li>
        <li data-row-internalnumber="1 023">+345 551 023</li>
        <li data-row-internalnumber="500 1">+345 555 001</li>
        <li data-row-internalnumber="456">+456 555 4156</li>
        <li data-row-internalnumber="345">+345 555 345</li>
        <li data-row-internalnumber="3 333">+55 333333333</li>
        <li data-row-internalnumber="4 444">+4444 55 555</li>
    </ul>
    <script src="js/jQuery.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script>
        $('li').each(function() {
            var attr = $(this).attr('data-row-internalnumber');
            if (attr !== undefined && attr !== "") {
                var totalLetters = 0, 
                numbers = [], 
                numbersMatch = true, 
                orginalText = $(this).text(),
                compare = attr.replace(/[\+\s]/g, '').split('').reverse(), 
                orginalTextReversed = orginalText.split('').reverse();

                for (var i = 0; i < compare.length; i++) {
                    if (orginalTextReversed[i] === ' ') {
                        totalLetters++;
                        numbers.push(orginalTextReversed[i]);
                        orginalTextReversed.splice(i, 1);
                    }
                    if (compare[i] === orginalTextReversed[i]) {
                        totalLetters++;
                        numbers.push(orginalTextReversed[i]);
                    } else {
                        numbersMatch = false;
                    }
                }
                if (numbersMatch) {
                    $(this).html(orginalText.substring(0, orginalText.length - totalLetters) + "<strong>" + numbers.reverse().join('') + "</strong>");
                }
            }
        });

    </script>
```

Comment: can you provide a fiddle? --> jsfiddle.net

Comment: Can you give a sample of the expected output?

Comment: sample output will be very helpful

Comment: you mean to say that the output is going to be the same as you have provided in the fiddle, the only difference being the use of regex, right ?

Comment: Yeah, the code works that I provided but I thought it was very messy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not very sure why the b tabs are not getting interpreted as bold tags but this is all I could come up with for you

```
$('li').each(function () {
    var attr = $(this).attr('data-row-internalnumber');
    var num = attr.replace(/[\+\s]/g,'');

    var finalnum = num.split('').join('\\s?').replace(/\"/,'');
    console.log(finalnum);
    var re = new RegExp("("+finalnum+")$");
    console.log(re);
    var oldval = $(this).html();
    $(this).html(oldval.replace(re,'<b>$1</b>'));
});
```

this selects the number in data-row-internalnumber and then creates a regex to finally search and replace from the original data.

Hope this is some help to you

fiddle here :  http://jsfiddle.net/7y9mX/2/

In the meanwhile I ll try figuring something out

Comment: Hei, This look cleaner than I did, the bold is not showing up because you using .text() instead of .html(). but it is numbers everywhere in the string that gets change, I wanted only to change the numbers in the end of the field if they match the internal numbers, the last one should not get changed as it is in the start of the string.

Comment: That is actually perfect, so much cleaner than I did. actually going to check the performance against what I did, great help thank you :)